# Delphi Initialize Const Array Of Record

Tags: delphi

Does anyone know if it is possible to initialize a record constant array?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click( Sender: TObject );
type
  TMyRec = record
    A: Integer;
  end;
const
  MyArray: TArray< TMyRec > = [ ?, ?, ? ];
begin

end;
```

thanks!

Comment: `TArray<TMyRec>` is a *dynamic* array of `TMyRec`. You want `MyArr: array[0..2] of TMyRec = ((...`

Comment: Thanks, but the code below compiles, I remember that at some point I had used a syntax that allowed this.
const
   MyArray: TArray <string> = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

Comment: If so, that was an *inline* const declaration. But the constant in that case isn't a static array, but a dynamic array.

Comment: There isn't a static array in the question

Comment: thanks David, i edit my title!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Every time you have a question about Delphi, the official documentation should be the first place you visit.

In this case, combining the knowledge from sections [Array Constants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Array_Constants) and [Record Constants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Record_Constants), we realise that the following syntax is valid:

```pascal
type
  TMyRec = record
    A, B: Integer;
  end;

const
  MyArray: array[0..2] of TMyRec =
    (
      (A: 1; B: 5),
      (A: 2; B: 10),
      (A: 3; B: 15)
    );
```

---

Initially, the question talked about static arrays, but its suggestion `TArray<TMyRec>` is in fact a *dynamic array*. By definition, `TArray<T> = array of T`.

Since Delphi XE7, you *can* create dynamic array typed constants, as long as the elements are of simple enough types:

```
const
  A: TArray<Integer> = [11, 22, 33];
  S: TArray<string> = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'];
```

---

Since Delphi 10.3, you can even make *inline* constant declarations, in which case the RHS can even depend on runtime functions. But these are quite far from "true" constants. Think of them as read-only (or assign-once) variables:

```pascal
begin
  const MyArray: TArray<TPoint> = [Point(1, 5), Point(2, 10), Point(3, 15)];
```

Hence, if you make a function that creates your record (perhaps a record constructor), you can use an inline constant declaration to create such a constant dynamic array of your record:

```pascal
type
  TMyRec = record
    A, B: Integer;
  end;

function MyRec(A, B: Integer): TMyRec;
begin
  Result.A := A;
  Result.B := B;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  const MyArray: TArray<TMyRec> = [MyRec(1, 5), MyRec(2, 10), MyRec(3, 15)];
end;
```

If you are willing to give up some type compatibility, you can also use type inference:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  const MyArray = [MyRec(1, 5), MyRec(2, 10), MyRec(3, 15)];
end;
```

Comment: The most interesting thing is when I have dynamic fields it compiles

type
  TMyRec = record
    A: Char;
    B: TArray< Integer >;
    C: TArray< string >;
  end;

const
  MyArray: array [ 0 .. 1 ] of TMyRec = ( ( A: 'A'; B: [ 1, 2, 3 ]; C: [ 'abc', 'def', 'ghi' ] ),
                                          ( A: 'B'; B: [ 4, 5, 6 ]; C: [ 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr' ] ) );

Comment: @DelphiUser: You are right. You can declare non-inline dynamic array constants. I'll update my answer.

Comment: A variant without an additional function is a class function directly next to the TMyRec record definition: class function MyRec(A, B: Integer): TMyRec; static;

Comment: @Pavel: Correct. But then it is arguably even better to use a constructor: `constructor Create(A, B: Integer);`

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes. I would forget about that. I have several variants with different overloads, so I have functions.